# Conditional calculation using raster calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, conditional

I have two rasters with the same extent, resolution, and projection, let's say raster A & B.
What I want to do is something like this:

```
IF A = 3 OR A = 11 THEN A+B
ELSE B
```

How can I do such a thing with a raster calculator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
(A@1 = 3 + A@1 = 11)* A@1 + B@1
```

1. `@1` means the first band of the raster
2. `A@1 = 3` returns `1` (TRUE) if A is 3
3. When A is 3 or 11, `(A@1 = 3 + A@1 = 11)` part returns `1`. Otherwise it returns `0`.

Comment: I test it and it works just fine, but I don't really understand the A@1 + B@1 part of the syntax how can it returns B when the condition is false? Can you elaborate on that part?

Comment: @MuhamadNasirLukman When the condition is false (i.e. A is neither 3 or 11), both of the `A@1 = 3` and `A@1 = 11` return `0`. Then the overall expression becomes `0 * A + B` and ends with `B`.