# How do I use the GDAL raster calculator in QGIS to calculate P using conditional equations based on pixel values in another layer?

Tags: qgis, gdal

I am trying to calculate PNET (net precipitation) values using the GDAL raster calculator in QGIS. However, I want to use different equations depending on the pixel values in another layers that I have P and LAI.

Specifically, if the pixel value in the LAI layer is less than 1, I want to use the following equation:

```
PNET = 0.04 + 0.99 × P - 0.09 × LAI
```

If the pixel value in the LAI layer is greater than or equal to 1, I want to use one of two equations depending on the value of P:

- If P is less than 0.6, use: 0`.03 + 0.72 × P - 0.05 × log(LAI)`
- If P is greater than or equal to 0.6, use: `-0.02 + 0.98 × P - 0.09 × LAI`

How can I express these conditions in a single GDAL raster calculator expression in QGIS?

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345141/conditional-calculation-using-raster-calculator-in-qgis?rq=1) might help. I haven't tried it myself. But based on what I'm reading there, you can try something in the gist of `(LAI < 1)*(0.04+0.99*P-0.09*LAI)+(LAI = 1 + LAI > 1)*((P<0.6)*(0.03+0.72*P-0.05*log(LAI)) + (P=0.6 + P>0.6)*(-0.02+0.98*P-0.09*LAI))` I have not used conditions in the raster calculator until now. So I can't guaranty this works.

Comment: Thank you for your comment; this was the answer that I was looking for, using QGIS. However, the process is really slow; it takes more than 30 mins to process 650 raster files. 
Just as a comment, in order for this solution to work in the GDAL calculator, it is necessary to use A, B, ... instead of LAI and P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a lot of raster processing (mostly biophysical data like yourself) and in my experience, map algebra more complicated than result = map1 + map2 is very cumbersome in both QGIS and Arc, and the various map algebra tools in QGIS are all insufficient in different ways. It's actually quite simple to do these calculations in Python, and you can do some wild stuff using numpy notation. Here's a simple ChatGPT example that will get you started:

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal

def process_rasters(file_dict, expression):
    # Open raster files and store them as NumPy arrays in a new dictionary
    raster_data = {}
    for key, file in file_dict.items():
        dataset = gdal.Open(file)
        band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
        raster_data[key] = band.ReadAsArray()

    # Evaluate the expression using the raster_data dictionary
    result_raster = eval(expression, {}, raster_data)

    return result_raster

# Example usage
raster_files = {
    'raster1': 'path/to/raster1.tif',
    'raster2': 'path/to/raster2.tif',
    'raster3': 'path/to/raster3.tif',
}

expression = "(raster1 + raster2) * raster3"
result = process_rasters(raster_files, expression)
```

And then you'll need something to save 'result' to a raster file, here is the function I use:

```
def array2raster(out_filename, reference_raster, array):
    """Writes a numpy raster to a geotiff file. Uses the metadata from the
    passed in reference_raster (which should be of type osgeo.gdal.Dataset).
    Uses -9999 as the NODATA_VALUE.
    """
    #print array
    geotransform = reference_raster.GetGeoTransform()
    originX = geotransform[0]
    originY = geotransform[3]
    pixelWidth = geotransform[1]
    pixelHeight = geotransform[5]
    cols = reference_raster.RasterXSize
    rows = reference_raster.RasterYSize

    driver = osgeo.gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    outRaster = driver.Create(out_filename, cols, rows, 1, osgeo.gdal.GDT_Float32)
    outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
    outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
    outband.SetNoDataValue(-9999)
    outband.WriteArray(array)
    outband.SetNoDataValue(-9999)
    outRasterSRS = osgeo.osr.SpatialReference()
    outRasterSRS.ImportFromWkt(reference_raster.GetProjectionRef())
    outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
    outband.FlushCache()
```

Note that this requires that your data is all of the same extent and has the same cell size (and cell size unit) - but without that, you're already in for a world of pain anyway, so I strongly suggest you do that anyway.

In your case, the expression would be something like 'PNET[LAI < 1] = NET = 0.04 + 0.99 × P - 0.09 × LAI' and then some more statements that implement your other formulas, like 'PNET[LAI >= 1] = ...' etc. (copy/pasting your formula into ChatGPT prefixed with 'numpy expression for the following:' gives a good starting point).

This is not an answer to your question, but in my experience this approach is a lot less frustrating than the way you're trying to do it, and easier in the long run like in the inevitable case you'll have to redo your calculations at some point in the future. All python and python libraries are already included if you have QGIS installed, just copy/paste the above into a file calc_pnet.py and do "\apps\python39\python.exe calc_pnet.py" if you're on Windows.

Then again I'm a programmer so maybe my perspective is skewed.

Comment: Indeed you are right; I managed to do the calculation as I intended in the question however the process takes too much time. I will work on python from now. I appreciate your comment!